# Auto Restart Nodejs Socket.io Application on System Reboot

Tags: node.js, linux, socket.io, pm2, forever

The situation is, I'm using Socket.io for a chat application using node js (AWS EC2 Linux).
For other applications, PM2 is working fine since I use Express with Node js.

PM2 does not work with Socket.io because here I'm using http to listen.

var http = require('http');
So I have to go with Forever.
But forever does not work with crontab in linux since I want the app started on system reboot.
I tried forever-service to start the app during reboot. But I get this error
**forever-service must run as root.**
So I tried with **sudo forever-service install test**

Then it throws **sudo: forever-service: command not found**

I want my Chat application to auto restart on system reboot. Please help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52566563/how-to-use-socket-io-in-angular-with-node-js refer this querstion and comments links maybe u got solution

Comment: `PM2 does not work with Socket.io because here I'm using http to listen.` this is not true, I have at least 10 socket.io servers running with PM2, why do you say that, what error do you get?